# What are the UI components for ImageSlider in React-Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I m newbie to this Facebook's React-native framework and android as well.I have trouble finding the right UI component for the below UI design. Can anyone list out the UI components for the below design? I want to know the UI Component for image slider. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I am currently using [react-native-viewpager](https://github.com/race604/react-native-viewpager) which is good enough for simple sliding operations.
There is also [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) component with advanced options but is currently doesnt support android.